# Section close/open with partial refresh

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I have a section in my xpage, it's open by default. When i close the section and make a partial refresh it opens the section again.

Is there a easy way the prevent this.

Comment: Hi Pixel, how have you defined the default? Normaly the section should not go back to its default even if you do a full refresh.

Comment: Hi, this is exactly my problem. The default is closed, but when i open a section and make a refresh is closes the section again. This is realy annoying for the enduser.

Answer (score 0):

Hehe, according to your problem i build a small XPage to test what i commented here is what i got:

```
<xp:panel id="refresh">
    <xp:section id="section1" initClosed="false">
        <xp:panel id="innerRefresh">Section content</xp:panel>
    </xp:section>
</xp:panel>

<xp:button value="refresh inner div" id="button3">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="innerRefresh">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://refresh}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

<xp:button value="refresh outer div" id="button4">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="refresh">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://refresh}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

<xp:button value="refresh section" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
        refreshId="section1">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://refresh}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>

    <xp:button value="full refresh" id="button2">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://refresh}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
```

By trying to refresh the sction in differen ways i saw nothing unusual if i pressed each button once or twice with about one secound in between, but if you press the button "refresh section" multiple times the section opens again. This effekt works in my IE8 and Firefox 19.0.2. I would recomend using a panel/div around your section and refresh it instead of the section direkt.

**Update:**

Try this, it creates up to 3 sections dynamical and each refreshable by its own button, and they will stay closed,

```
<xp:this.beforePageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var sectioncount:java.util.Vector = @Explode("1,2,3",",");
viewScope.put("sectioncount",sectioncount);
viewScope.put("selectedSection", sectioncount)

}]]></xp:this.beforePageLoad>

<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1"
        value="#{viewScope.selectedSection}">
        <xp:this.defaultValue><![CDATA[#{javascript:return viewScope.get( "sectioncount" );}]]></xp:this.defaultValue>
        <xp:eventHandler event="onchange" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:// full update //partial update}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return viewScope.get( "sectioncount" );}]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>


    <xp:repeat id="repeat2" rows="30" var="varcollection"
        repeatControls="true">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:return viewScope.get( "sectioncount" );}]]></xp:this.value>
            <xp:panel>
                            <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:var vec:java.util.Vector = viewScope.get( "selectedSection" );
return @IsMember(varcollection,vec);
}]]></xp:this.rendered>
                            <xp:button value="refresh this section:" id="button3">
                <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial"
                    refreshId="refresh">
                    <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript://refresh}]]></xp:this.action>
                </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:button>
                <xp:panel id="refresh">
                    <xp:section id="section1" initClosed="false">
                        <xp:panel id="innerRefresh">

                            <xp:text>
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var date:java.util.Date = new java.util.Date;
return date.toTimeString()}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:text></xp:panel>
                    </xp:section>                   
                </xp:panel>
                </xp:panel>
     </xp:repeat>
```

Comment: My problem is, that i have to refresh multiple sections and the number of sections are dynamically configurable, so i do not know how many there are. I need a good way to set the status of these section persistant.